# How to add a key for glossaries which mirrors \glssymbol?

Tags: luatex, glossaries, unicode-math

At the moment i'm writing a text with lots of equations and not less variables. So 'Thank God' for the glossaries-package. To minimize the actual code i added an extra key 'derivative', which resulted in a unexpected behaivour. However, this is conform to the use of the \glsuseri-command.

Question: how can i modify the new key so it mirrors \glssymbol?
(meaning: i want that dot above the variable instead of a line through it)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec-luatex}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{unicode-math-luatex}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsaddkey{derivative}
{\glsentrytext{todo}}
{\glsentryDerivative}
{\GlsentryDerivative}
{\glsDerivative}
{\GlsDerivative}
{\GLSDerivative}

\newglossaryentry{testTarget}
{
    name={testTarget},
    symbol={\symbfit{V} },
    derivative={\dot{\symbfit{V}} },
    description={testDesc}
}
\newglossaryentry{test}
{
    name={testVar1},
    symbol={\dot{\symbfit{V}} },
    user1={\dot{\symbfit{V}} },
    description={testDesc}
}

\begin{document}

Glossary variable ....
\begin{align}
\glssymbol{testTarget} \\
\glsDerivative{testTarget}
\end{align}

in comparison
\begin{align}
\glssymbol{test} \\
\glsuseri{test}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which results for me in
[image: compiled text]

Comment: Try adding `\glssetnoexpandfield{derivative}` after you define the `derivative` key or put `\glsnoexpandfields` before `\glsaddkey`.

Comment: Well, it can be so simple sometimes - Thank you very much! PS now i found the related section the glossary doc ^^# (if you know what you're looking for i guess its always easy)